# CToolBar MFC 64-bit crash when it runs on 32-bit

Tags: c++, .net, mfc

I have an a application in c++98 which works fine in 32 bits. But in 64 bits it crashes randomly start. Maybe in 10 times it doesn't crash at all of a sudden it crashes 3 times in a row.

This crash happens during the creation of the menu bar. This menu bar is a class that inherits from `CToolBar`.

```
const DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY;

m_menuBar.SetSizes( CSize( 16,15 ), CSize( 1,1 ) );
const BOOL bCreated = m_menuBar.CreateEx( this, TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_LIST, dwStyle, CRect(0,0,0,0), AFX_IDW_TOOLBAR );
```

Recently by a decision of our manager we updated from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2019, and now the crash happen systematically in 64bit and still doesn't happen in 32bit.

What could be the problem?

Edit for adding my stack:

```
Kernel.dll!000000001f009540()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7c63ed()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7c5fbc()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7d28d3()
ntdll.dll!00007fff7e4dfe14()
win32u.dll!00007fff7c4c1f24()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7b8011()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7b7c04()
user32.dll!00007fff7c7db122()
mfc140d.dll!00007fff3ba05208()
mfc140d.dll!00007fff3b9f4e56()
mfc140d.dll!00007fff3b9f4715()
mfc140d.dll!00007fff3b84a4c3()
d.exe!CDcmMainFrame::CreateMenuBar() Line 1001
d_d.exe!CDcmMainFrame::OnCreate(tagCREATESTRUCTA * lpCreateStruct) Line 925
[External Code]
d_d.exe!CVSDicomApp::InitInstance() Line 3074
[External Code]
d.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26
d_d.exe!main(int ac, char * * av) Line 24
[External Code]
```

Comment: I've read the doc. of [CMFCMenuBar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=vs-2019#createex) to find some of the usual traps I remember from when we switched from x86 to x64. I couldn't. What if the `this` isn't as expected (i.e. this is a follow-up to something else which broke earlier)? A specific issue, I can remember: Handles were stored as `DWORD` which is fine in x86 but may break in x64. That's underhanded because handles may have values where the upper 32 bits are 0. In this case, it works - you don't notice the failure.

Comment: And _where_ does it crash exactly? The call stack will tell you where exactly in MFC the crash happens.

Comment: Maybe you store pointers as DWORDs somewhere or something similar. This is a classic one.

Comment: The stack say it crash in the CreateEx line... I tried to review all the pointers and don't seem to be the case but maybe i skipped something. The application is a bit caotic.

Comment: @Jalg Is it the `this` pointer? Or is the crash actually in `SetSizes`? Put a breakpoint there and check.

Comment: @Jalg  Please [edit] the question and add the stack trace. Does it crash in debug and in release mode? Please put all relevant information into the question.

Comment: I edited right know with the stack trace. And it is in the call of createEx the this pointer have info and the setsizes didn't affect at all. In release happens to.

Comment: @sch: GDI/USER handles are 32 bit, even in 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the root cause is located outside the code you posted and that it's related to an invalid pointer conversion. It would be helpful to know more about the context of your code.
What I could image:

- Your posted code is located inside a method of a CWnd-derived class.
- A pointer to that class is converted and stored within a 32-bit integer.
- The method is called through a pointer to that class that is generated by converting the 32-bit integer back to the pointer of your class.
- On a 64-bit system, this results in clearing out the upper 32 bits of your pointer.
- In case these bits were zero, nothing will happen, because the pointer is not changed.
- In case these bits were nonzero, the pointer gets damaged and points to an invalid memory region. Finally, this damaged pointer is represented by "this" when calling CreateEx which finally accesses a wrong memory location.
- On a 32-bit system, the code works because pointers are 32 bits only and do not get truncated when casted to 32-bit integers.

You could try the following:

Insert a

```
Trace("*** MyClass = %p ***\n", this);
```

call into both, the constructor of your class and directly before the CreateEx call. Do the two debug outputs match in case of a crash?

One further thing you could try is setting a breakpoint to the CreateEx call, so that the execution stops before CreateEx is called. Then inspect the "this" pointer. Do all members of the class look valid? Especially m_hWnd should be != NULL. (Of course, this has to be evaluated for the case that the crash occurs, so you might need to try multiple times, since you do not know that in advance.) Also, you might output the m_hWnd once directly after creating your "this" window and directly before the CreateEx call. Are they equal?

If I got that right, the code is located in your main application - not within a dll, correct? (I had some strange behaviour in the past when creating MFC objects in dlls and when I forgot the AFX_MANAGE_STATE macro.)

Are you using multiple threads in your application? May it be that the CreateEx call is sometimes done by a different thread? MFC gets into trouble when mixing MFC calls from different threads within one class. You may expand the debug outputs from above to

```
    Trace("*** MyClass = %p, ThreadId = %u ***\n", this, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

(The thread Ids should always be equal as the "this" pointers.)

Comment: The call of this create menu is in the MainFrame derived class from COXFrameWndSizeDock. I will try to find some pointer similar than you define.

Comment: This is the output whith both trace:

atlTraceGeneral - *** MyClass = 000000001BB5C1E0 ***
atlTraceGeneral - *** MyClass = 000000001BB5C1E0 ***

So yes are the same...

Comment: There's no need to add any code just for dumping some pieces of information. You can [log info with tracepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints) instead.

Comment: Some of the members are null but m_hWnd isn't.

Comment: Is not null when crash but it say is unused=???, which i don't now what it means or if is normal.

Yes is located in my main application. I am trying to solve some warning related with 32/64 bits problems that pvs remarks me without success.

The application is multithread but i think the start is always the main thread i will watch this with more attention.